# Why is the measurement yielding only one single outcome questioned in Wigner's friend extended?

Tags: quantum-information, measurements

So in the Wikipedia article and paper it references of [Wigner's friend extended](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07422):

> Roughly speaking, those assumptions are
>
> (Q): Quantum theory is correct.
>
> (C): Agent's predictions are information-theoretically consistent.
>
> (S): A measurement yields only one single outcome.

I fail to see how the measurement or (S) has anything to do with it? I mean the whole thing can be reformulated in terms of density matrices (which eliminates any possibility of (S) being the source of the problem) and one still gets a difference of descriptions of density matrices.

Is my assumption that the density matrix description can be used to eliminate the (S) wrong?